# habilitar e desabilitar butão em react

Tags: react, button, jsx

estou fazendo um quis de perguntas em react, na qual faço uma requisição pro banco e ele retorna as pergunta e assim eu crio o front, só que o botão de responder eu só quero que seja ativado quando o usuário clicar em alguns dos input de resposta, quando o usuário clica o estado e alterado o botão e ativado, mas ele ativa todos os botões de todas as outras pergunta também, eu queria que ativasse somente o daquela pergunta na qual o input foi clicado, como posso fazer isso?
meu código:

const [estadoBtn,setEstadoBtn]= useState(true)

```
function ativaBtnResposta(event){ // vai na div inputs
        let alvo=event.currentTarget
        let id=alvo.parentElement.id
        let box=document.getElementById(id)
        let input=box.querySelectorAll('.boxResposta input')
        let btnRes=box.querySelector('.resposta button')
        
        input.forEach(element => {
            if(element.checked){
                setEstadoBtn(false)
               
            }
            
        });




 return(
<div> 
 <h1>quiz<h1>
 {cont.map((id,index) =>{
return( 
  <div key={index} className="boxQuest" id={id._id}>
   div className="inputs" onClick={ativaBtnResposta} >
                            <div className="boxResposta">
                                <input type="radio" name="resposta" value='A'  ></input>
                                <p>A - {id.A}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="boxResposta">
                                <input type="radio" name="resposta" value='B'  ></input>
                                <p>B - {id.B}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="boxResposta">
                                <input type="radio" name="resposta" value='C'  ></input>
                                <p>C - {id.C}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="boxResposta">
                                <input type="radio" name="resposta" value='D'  ></input>
                                <p>D - {id.D}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div className="boxResposta">
                                <input type="radio" name="resposta" value='E'  ></input>
                                <p>E - {id.E}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

   
</div>
<div className="resposta">
  <button className="btnRespostaHtml" disabled={estadoBtn}onClick{showResposta}>Responder</button>
  <span className="showRes">{id.res}</span>
</div>


)

 




</div>

)
```

Comment: O código está uma bagunça muito grande, mas a ideia é a mesma por trás do React como um todo: suas perguntas devem ser "encapsuladas" em um componente, assim o state vai se referir àquela pergunta e nenhuma outra. Ou, ativando o modo programação orientada a mangue, num componente só, é só fazer um state contendo um objeto composto, com um subitem para cada pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

Opa, tudo certo?

Primeiramente, no React temos o princípio da imutabilidade, na qual elementos em React são imutáveis, ou seja, não podem mudar seus atributos uma vez que criados.

Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta, tu quer que cada botão seja ativado apenas quando clicar no input do tipo radio daquela pergunta. Mas quando você clica em um todos os botões ficam habilitados.
Se for isso, isso acontece pois a mesma variável é usada para todos os botões no mesmo contexto. Para resolver isso, tu pode fazer um componente representando um conjunto de input/label/button e recebendo a questão como parâmetro. Eu fiz aqui em typescript, vou te enviar e veja se te ajuda em algo.

Arquivo App.tsx (tsx é react com typescript)
import { Input } from "./input";
import "./styles.css";

```
export default function App() {
  const questions = ["question1", "question2", "question3"];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {questions.map((question) => {
        return <Input question={question} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Arquivo Input.tsx (é o componente que criei)

```
import { useState } from "react";

interface InputProps{
  question: string
}

export function Input({question}: InputProps) {
  const [questionIsSelected, setQuestionIsSelected] = useState(false);

  function inputIsFocus() {
    setQuestionIsSelected(true);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label htmlFor="">{question}</label>
      <input type="radio" onClick={inputIsFocus} />
      <button disabled={!questionIsSelected}>Enviar</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Não fiz seguindo todos os padrões de clean code etc, tentei deixar de um jeito mais fácil de entender pelo que entendi de sua necessidade.

Espero ter ajudado!